# Get request doesn't work server side

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am making basic web server using nodejs and express module. It has to be able to respond to `POST` and `GET` requests. `POST` is just working fine, but `GET`doesn't return anything. In console there's a textStatus of an error `parserror` and `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Object.parse (native) at jQuery.parseJSON` error. I'm new to NodeJS and Express, please tell me where I went wrong.

```
var express = require('express'),
    server = express(),
    fs = require('fs');

server.use(express.static('../client'));

server.post('/students.json', function (req, res) {
    var bodyStr = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        bodyStr += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        fs.readFile('students.json', function (err, data) {
            var encodedObj = data.toString('utf8'), //encoding what's inside of .json into human symbols
                parsedObj = JSON.parse(encodedObj);
            parsedObj.push(JSON.parse(bodyStr)); //adding newly created parsed obj into array 

            fs.writeFile('students.json', JSON.stringify(parsedObj), function (err) { //rewriting file with new array
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
});

server.get('/students.json', function (req, res) {//what's wrong???
    res.send(); 
});

var server = server.listen(8888);
```

Comment: Running it here didn't produce any errors. It correctly returned nothing when calling a get to `/students.json` on my computer. I would assume it must be in code elsewhere?

Comment: That's the issue, I want to return students.json file back to client. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to res.send()?  It looks empty to me.  Try:

```
res.send('Hello World!'); // A string
```

...or...

```
res.send([{'name': 'Joe Student'},{'name': 'Sally Goestoskuhl'}]); // Array
```

...or...

```
res.send({}); // Empty json response
```

...or...

```
res.send(404); // Any integer is considered an HTTP error code
```

...or...

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify({ variable: 'value' }));
```

...or...

```
// Assuming your json is in the public folder...
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'students.json'));
```

Comment: I want to send my students.json file. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`res.send();` on it's own just sends an empty response.
If you then try to `json_decode` it, you'll get an error.

If I interpret your question correctly, you want both POST and GET to return the same result?

You could do this pretty simply like this:

```
function sendJSON(req, res)
{
   //JSON code from your existing server.post
}

app.get('/students.json', sendJSON);
app.post('/students.json', sendJSON);
```

Comment: In fact i want to return json file. I am fetching it from a client side using Backbone. That might sound really simple, but I really cannot find an answer how to do that.